# How to find number of occurrence for each element in grails?

Tags: grails

I want to get count for all numbers and its occurrence.
like 1=4,2=3,etc

```
def list=[1,1,1,2,1,2,3,2,3,4,9,4,6,3,6]
```

Comment: list.count(value) should do you: http://mrhaki.blogspot.de/2009/12/groovy-goodness-counting-items-in-list.html

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
def list=[1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,1,6,4,6,5,4]
def countMap=[:]
 list.each{
  if(countMap[it]){
   countMap[it]=countMap[it]+1
  }else{
   countMap[it]=1
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
assert list.countBy { it } == [1:4, 2:3, 3:3, 4:2, 9:1, 6:2]
```